# Combine Multiple Column values into one Row

Tags: oracle

I have the data like below where I want to combine the rows having  null values with not null values.

```
ID    ColA    ColB      ColC     ColD
1     A1      B1        null     null
1     A2      B2        null     null
1     null    B3        C1       D1
2     A3      B3        null     null
3     null    null      C3       D3
```

Expected Result:

```
ID  ColA   ColB    ColC     ColD
1   A1      B1     C1       D1
1   A2      B2     C1       D1
2   A3      B3     null     null
3   null    null   C3       D3
```

Basically for a single ID multiple rows (different COLA)can exist but only one row with null ColA.

ColC and ColD will always be null for the rows having not null ColA.

I want to merge the ColB,ColC and ColD values of the row having null ColA with all the rows having not null ColA.

Comment: For a specific ID, there's always a row with ColA IS NULL or that row may or may not exist?

Comment: Possible scenarios:
1. Row with only null ColA.
2. Row with only not null ColA.
3. Row with null ColA and multiple rows with not null ColA

Comment: Then use a LEFT OUTER JOIN (see my answer). Use a FULL JOIN in case the row with ColA IS NOT NULL may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use two correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT ID,ColA,ColB,
       (SELECT ColC FROM table y 
        WHERE x.id = y.id AND ColA IS NULL) As ColC,
       (SELECT ColD FROM table y 
        WHERE x.id = y.id AND ColA IS NULL) As ColD
FROM table x
WHERE ColA IS NOT NULL
```

Another way is to use a self join

```
SELECT x.ID,x.ColA,x.ColB,
       y.ColC,y.ColD
FROM table x
JOIN table y
ON x.ID = y.ID AND x.ColA IS NOT NULL AND y.ColA IS NULL
```

---

**EDIT**

---

> If for a particular ID only one row with not null ColA value

I guess you mean that there is no row with ColA = NULL at all for particular id.
In this case the first query will work, and the second query must use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT x.ID,x.ColA,x.ColB,
       y.ColC,y.ColD
FROM table x
LEFT JOIN table y
ON x.ID = y.ID AND x.ColA IS NOT NULL AND y.ColA IS NULL
```

---

> or a row having only null ColA

In this case the condition must be extended with NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT ID,ColA,ColB,
       (SELECT ColC FROM table y 
        WHERE x.id = y.id AND ColA IS NULL) As ColC,
       (SELECT ColD FROM table y 
        WHERE x.id = y.id AND ColA IS NULL) As ColD
FROM table x
WHERE ColA IS NOT NULL
  OR NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM table z
     WHERE  x.id = z.id AND z.ColA IS NOT NULL
  )
```

---

```
SELECT x.ID,x.ColA,x.ColB,
       y.ColC,y.ColD
FROM table x
LEFT JOIN table y
ON x.ID = y.ID AND y.ColA IS NULL
WHERE x.ColA IS NOT NULL 
   OR NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM table z
         WHERE  x.id = z.id AND z.ColA IS NOT NULL
      )
```

Comment: I also have one more question.If for a particular ID only one row with not null ColA value (or a row having only null ColA) exist  then how to return that row too in the resut set.. The self join will result in the rows for which corresponding rows having null ColA exists,rt?

Comment: @sqlpractice I have extended the answer to additional cases

Comment: @ krokodilkoI have edited the Data Set and the expected result. Can you please advise the solution for the updated expected result. Also Is there a way to avoid the Not exists subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT filled.ID,
       filled.ColA,
       filled.ColB AS ColB_1,
       empty.ColB  AS ColB_2,
       empty.ColC,
       empty.ColD
FROM   my_table filled
JOIN   my_table empty
  ON   filled.ID = empty.ID
 AND   empty.ColA IS NULL
WHERE  filled.ColA IS NOT NULL;
```

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in case the row with `ColA IS NULL` may not exist.